# In template argument deduction how does sqrt<T>(complex<T>) matche sqrt<T>(<T>) function call?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, template-argument-deduction

```
template<class T> T sqrt (T);
template<class T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);
double sqrt(double);
void f(complex<double> z)
{
    sqrt(z);
}
```

In this code how does `sqrt<double>(complex<double>)` end up as a candidate for
template argument deduction?
And the author says any call that matches `sqrt<T>(complex<T>)` also matches `sqrt<T>(<T>)`. How?

Code is from *The C++ Programming Language*, by Bjarne Stroustrup. Section 13.3.2

Comment: A call to `foo(something_concrete)` matches a call to `foo(anything)`, that makes sense to me. Of course, out of the two, the compiler will chose the more specialized one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `z` is of type `complex<double>`. With `T` being `double` it clearly matches

```
template <typename T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);
```

Also, with `T` being `complex<double>` it matches

```
template <typename T> T sqrt(T);
```

Where is the problem with this?

As the result of matching both of these functions, the overload set for deciding which of the functions to use consists of the two instantiations

```
complex<double> sqrt<double>(complex<double>)
complex<double> sqrt<complex<double>>(complex<double>)
```

Both match but the first one is more specialized and, thus, chosen by the overload resolution.